# R Markdown: how to arrange many images from file in a grid

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have 100 images saved as .png files. I'd like to display them all as a 10x10 grid of images, such that each image has its own title and the grid of images shares a single caption. I'd like to use R Markdown to do this. Is this possible?

Comment: One possible approach could be to make a collage image with component titles using `imagemagick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach with {ggplot2} and {cowplot}:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

## data frame with image positions on a 10 x 10 grid,
## increasing from top left to bottom right (change as needed):
positions <- expand.grid(x = 0:9, y = 9:0)

## paths to images, use `list.files()` etc. for convenience:
file_names <- c('path/to/img1.png', 'path/to/img2.png')

## tile images with `draw_image` on an empty `ggplot` object:
seq_along(file_names) |>
  Map(f = \(i){
    draw_image(file_names[i], 
               x = .1 * positions$x[i],
               y = .1 * positions$y[i],
               width = .1, height = .1
               )
  }) |>
  Reduce(f = \(collage, next_tile) collage + next_tile, init = ggplot()) +
  coord_fixed() +
  theme_void()
```