# R markdown: click on panel in figure and open that panel to full size

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have 100 images saved as .png files. I'd like to display them all as a 10x10 grid of images, such that each image has its own title and the grid of images shares a single caption. Also, when a panel is clicked, I want that .png file to open such that it can be downloaded individually. I'd like to use R Markdown to do this. Is this possible?

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78104808/r-markdown-how-to-arrange-many-images-from-file-in-a-grid/78106392#78106392) without the request to click on a panel and download it.

Comment: Have you tried anything? You may find some averse to "code this for me" questions.

Comment: Aside from googling I wasn't sure how to approach this or if it was even possible. Even just being pointed to packages or tools that could do this is helpful.

Comment: Please know that *"asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource"* is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on SO. Admittedly the preferred [softwarerecs.se] see much lower traffic, so it's not in my opinion a great alternative atm. It would not surprise me if you get downvotes or close votes for that; I tend not to (for my reason above), but some are less hesitant to do so. I hope the provided answer helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to the JavaScript library [freewall.js](https://kombai.github.io/freewall/).

Here is an example where I have 14 images in the **images/** subfolder:

````
---
title: "test freewall.js"
author: "Stéphane Laurent"
date: "2024-03-07"
output: 
  html_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.html
---

```{r, include=FALSE}
library(htmltools)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
imgs <- list.files("./images")
items <- lapply(imgs, function(image) {
  tags$div(
    class = "item", 
    tags$img(src = paste0("./images/", image))
  )
})
container <- as.character(
  do.call(function(...) tags$div(id = "container", ...), items)
)
cat(gsub("(\n|  |   )", "", container))
cat(as.character(
  tags$script('$(function() {var wall = new Freewall("#container");   wall.fitWidth();});')
))
```
````

File ***header.html***, to include in the same folder as the **Rmd**:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/freewall@1.0.8/freewall.min.js"></script>
<style>
  #container {
      width: 80%;
      margin: auto;
  }
  .item {
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
  }
</style>
```

[image]

I don't know how to request a 10x10 grid, here the grid is automatic. Maybe play with the width of the items.

To download an image, you can simply right-click on it.

---

## Edit: freewall package

I've started to do a package:

```r
remotes::install_github("stla/freewall")
```

````
---
title: "test freewall.js"
author: "Stéphane Laurent"
date: "2024-03-07"
output: html_document
---

```{r, include=FALSE}
library(freewall)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
imagesFolder <- "images"
imgs <- paste0(imagesFolder, "/", list.files(imagesFolder))
freewall(
  imgs, 
  widths = 150,
  width = "80%",
  cellW = 150,
  cellH = "auto",
  draggable = TRUE
)
```
````